# Can not find favicon's page url

Tags: android, chromium

Does anybody know where this error message comes from?
I keep getting it about every minute in my Android LGS. And there are 30 or so identical lines in the log every minute. 
Does anyone have similar issues?
Does anyone know how to further debug this issue?
I didn't find any helpful links, either...

The entry is: `E/chromium(xxxx): [ERROR:android_provider_backend.cc(851)] Can not find favicon's page url`

Comment: just encountered this and I just wanna tell you that its coming from chrome! lol